# javascript autoexecuted function syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found this function and I'm not sure about  what's doing

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /
        $('.auto-scroll').off('click').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ....
            ....
        });

        $("#btnBuscar").on("click", function() {
            ...
            ...
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

What is the meaning of pass JQuery as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the meaning of pass JQuery as a parameter?

It's passing `jQuery` as an argument, and receiving it as the `$` parameter. That way, within the anonymous function, it can use `$` when using jQuery, rather than having to use `jQuery`. This is useful when you can't be sure that the global `$` is already equal to `jQuery` (which it may not be, if a page has used `noConflict` to release it).